Solution to $\Delta u=\lambda u$
I was trying to solve $\Delta u=\lambda u$ on $B(0,1)$ with the boundary conditions=$0$ in 2 dimensions.
My attempt:
Assuming that my solution is radial $u=u(r)$,I get
$$ u_{rr} + \frac{u_r}{r}-\lambda u=0$$
I do not know how to solve this ODE. Can someone help?

Define "solution". You can match a power expansion and give it a name. Is that good enough? If so, you are in luck, since it has allready been done, as @YvesDaoust said, by Bessel

So, this is only solvable for $\lambda=-1$?
